# onrowupdating event not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I dont know why because `onrowdeleting` works fine
The delete method is in the same class as the update method

```
<form id="formulario" runat="server" method="post">
<asp:GridView AllowPaging="true" id="inf_clientes" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
 runat="server" GridLines="Both" BorderWidth="1" 
onrowdeleting="Grid_DeleteCommand" onrowupdating="Grid_UpdateCommanda"
DataKeyNames="cliente_id,nombre,apellido,celular">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton CommandName="Delete" runat="server" ValidationGroup="validation" ImageUrl="borrar.jpg" ToolTip="Borrar" Height="20px" Width="20px"  />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton CommanName="Update" ImageUrl="guardar.jpg" ValidationGroup="validation" runat="server" ToolTip="Guardar" Height="20px" Width="20px" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and code behind

```
protected void Grid_UpdateCommanda(object origen,GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {   


        con.Open();
        EjecutarComando = new SqlCommand("UPDATE dclntes SET nombre='c' where cliente_id=4",con);
        EjecutarComando.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Dispose();
        todos();
    }
```

If you need more let me know

Comment: Define "not working" did you put a breakpoint? Is the method called?

Comment: hi guys i just found the error, how do i delete this post?

Comment: the problem was that i wrote CommanName instead of CommandName in line 15

Comment: You have a "delete" link under the question, next to the keywords

Comment: its better to answer your self to your question and not delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I was told to answer myself so Im doing so:
The error was that wrote `CommanName` instead of `CommandName`. I dont know if it will help  someone but that was the problem.